# Show only categories within facet using ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have produced this figure:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
sites <-
structure(list(ecositeid = c("F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", 
"F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", 
"F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", 
"F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI200CA", 
"R018XI107CA", "F018XI200CA", "R018XI107CA", "R018XI107CA", "R018XI107CA", 
"R018XI107CA", "R018XI107CA", "R018XI107CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", 
"F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", 
"F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI200CA", "F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA", 
"F018XI205CA", "F018XI205CA"), coiid = c(627765L, 627766L, 627767L, 
627768L, 627871L, 635383L, 635385L, 635387L, 635389L, 635391L, 
635393L, 635395L, 635398L, 635401L, 635406L, 635409L, 634862L, 
637514L, 2630315L, 633648L, 2331930L, 2528931L, 2528931L, 2073965L, 
2073965L, 2073965L, 627934L, 627936L, 627941L, 627948L, 628062L, 
632891L, 632899L, 632907L, 632907L, 632913L, 627951L, 627960L, 
627969L, 628065L), elev_l = c(121.9000015, 121.9000015, 121.9000015, 
121.9000015, 121.9000015, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 
335, 335, 335, 335, 61, 243.8000031, 180, 43, 80, 75, 75, 65, 
65, 65, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61
), elev_rv = c(304.7999878, 304.7999878, 304.7999878, 304.7999878, 
304.7999878, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 473, 
473, 457, 548.5999756, 195, 80, 135, 105, 105, 90, 90, 90, 259, 
259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259
), elev_h = c(487.7000122, 487.7000122, 487.7000122, 487.7000122, 
487.7000122, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 610, 
610, 853, 853.5, 320, 116, 265, 205, 205, 145, 145, 145, 457, 
457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457, 457
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))

sites <- sites %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("elev_l", "elev_h", "elev_rv"), 
               names_to = "range") %>%
  mutate(coiid = factor(coiid))

sites %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = coiid)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center') + 
  facet_wrap(~ecositeid, dir = "v")
```

Within each facet, it shows all of the `coiid` categories. I only want it to show the `coiid` categories that are within the facet. For example, the correct solution should have the bottom facet with only the four `coiid` categories within that facet. This will save a lot of space.

How could I do this?

Comment: Try `scales = free` in `facet_wrap`.

Comment: scales = "free", yes, thank you!

Comment: @RuiBarradas actually, this applies different scales to the x axis. I want the same scale to be used for all facets, as was done originally.

Comment: But if the scale is the same for all facets, then how can you save space?

Comment: It is saving space along the y-axis by decreasing the clutter of a bunch of unnecessary ```coiid```s

Comment: Maybe `scales = "free_y"`, then.